# Finding the velocity of an impact test

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to find the velocity of an impact test.

I am using a drop hammer impact machine to hit some composite specimens.

I know the equation for the velocity is V = V<sub>0</sub> + at ——————- (1)

And that V<sub>0</sub> = V<sub>f</sub> - (at) ——————(2)

And V<sub>f</sub> = $\sqrt{2gh}$ ————- (3)

Where **V<sub>0</sub>** is the initial velocity, **a** is acceleration, **t** is time and **V<sub>f</sub>** is the final velocity.

I do not have the height **h** between the impactor and the impact specimen so I would need to rearrange equation (3) to get this, however I do not know the final velocity so how would I find the height **h** ?

I assumed that the initial velocity is 0 but then I seen equation (2) and this confused me

Comment: If you are performing a "test", how could you not know "h"?

Comment: You can't do much without $h$. You're asking what is the final speed of a falling object, without knowing if you dropped it off a table or a skyscraper - that will obviously make a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way these tests are done is you start at h and drop the weight on the specimen.  The energy = mgh.

from [google](https://www.worldoftest.com/drop-weight-impact-tester):

> Test pieces are subjected to blows from a falling striker, of specified mass and shape, dropped from a known height onto specified positions around the circumference of the test piece.

So you need the beginning height or nothing works.  Anything else is just equations for equations' sake.  Clearly the beginning and ending velocities are zero.

Comment: So if I use an impact energy of 50 j and I know the mass and gravity g, then I could rearrange this to find the height ?

Comment: yes you could.  Measuring height tends to be a lot easier than measuring energy or velocity

Comment: Okay thank you this makes a lot more sense

Answer (score 2):

If you are given

$$ V_F=\sqrt{2gh} $$

It is a given then that $V_0=0$

Answer (score 2):

How was the "test" setup? What measurement have you taken"?

Let's connect the dots:

$E = m(V_f^2 - V_0^2)/2 = mg\Delta h$; and

$V_f = V_0 + at$

For free-fall (implied by $mg\Delta h$), $V_0 = 0$; $\Delta h$ = distance travelled = $h$, so

$V_f = \sqrt{2gh} = at$, again, for free fall, $a = g$

Solving for $h$ as a function of $t$, we got:

$h = gt^2/2$

So, if you have timed the fall, you can get both the final velocity and the distance the object has traveled.

Comment: Thank you :) I didn’t time the fall but I know the energy which is 50 j , mass is 6.251 kg and g = 9.81 then using energy = mgh and rearranging for height h I get 0.82 m which seems pretty much correct

Comment: :) Physics is fun, isn't it?!

Comment: It certainly is :)